# to track all ancestors of a node in general tree using Stack

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree, stack

i have created the function to track the ancestors of a node in general tree using stack but it is not working need help   [image] Common ancestors of *(John, 1925)* and *(Fred, 1900)*: 
**(Fred, 1900)**
Common ancestors of *(John, 1925)* and *(Fred, 1953)*: 
**(John, 1925), (Fred, 1900)**

```
public void Find_FamilyTree(Node node,Node toFind,Stack<Node> st)
{

    st.push(node);
    if(node.getData().getName().equals(toFind.getData().getName()))
    {
        st.pop();
    }
```

if node is a leaf node then a pop

```
    if(node.getChildrenCount()==0)
    {
        st.pop();
    }


    for(Node nodes:node.getChildren())
    {
        Find_FamilyTree(nodes,toFind,st);
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you going top to down instead of down from the child to find to up?

Comment: because i don't have track of parent of the node.Node have it's data and child list only

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple.

just using DFS to trace the tree and push/pop the node when you enter/leave a node. return immediately only if you find the node,then you got a stack of ancestors.

an example as follows:

```
public boolean Find_FamilyTree(Node node,Node toFind,Stack<Node> st) {

    if(node.getData().getName().equals(toFind.getData().getName()))
    {
         return true;
    }
    st.push(node);

    for(Node nodes:node.getChildren())
    {
        if(Find_FamilyTree(nodes,toFind,st)){
           return true;
        }
    }

    st.pop(node);
    return false;

  }
```